# Performance of AES CTR + HMAC SHA1

Tags: aes, openssl, gcm, sha-1, ctr

I'm doing a performance test on AES with CTR mode and HMAC SHA1 for message authentication and found the `openssl speed` tool for that.

I run multiple tests with `openssl speed -evp sha1 aes-128-ctr aes-128-gcm` because I want to compare it to the GCM mode which do encryption and message authentication in a single mode.

Now my question: how can I compare these values?
Is the value of the sha1 result the "speed" of the combination of ctr + hmac sha1 because it's the bottleneck or do I have to subtract these two values to get the combined speed of ctr + hmac sha1?

[image]

Comment: HMAC-SHA-1 uses the double call of the SHA-1, one is long (almost hashes as same as the message size) and the other one is short, a single block of SHA1 (512-bit for SHA-1). Short messages suffer from initialization, you might need to consider your real case. For the interpretation of the output see [How can I interpret openssl speed output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17410270/1820553) from [so]. This is mostly off-topic.

Comment: There aren't any AES-CTR cipher suites. Although CTR is used as underlying tech for GCM, the MAC authenticated ciphersuites are all based on CBC, unfortunately using MAC-then-encrypt. Of course, as CTR and CBC use as many block encrypts, the speed difference *should* be negligible for sane implementations (but there is a lot of insanity in this world).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about interpreting the result of a cryptographic library. There is already [HMAC speed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58719049/1820553) on [so] already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the value of the sha1 result the "speed" of the combination of ctr + hmac sha1 because it's the bottleneck or do I have to subtract these two values to get the combined speed of ctr + hmac sha1?

First of all, you should use AES-CBC just to be sure that you are using the right combination of algorithms. AES-CBC is much slower than AES-CTR on my machine. This is probably due to buffering; it is possible to precalculate large parts of the key stream for AES-CTR.

TLS packets are usually about 1.5 K in size, so you could use the 1024 byte blocks as best indicator. I've done the speed test with SHA-1, AES-CBC as well as AES-GCM.

So let's use the following values:

```
SHA-1 (representing HMAC-SHA-1): 1467708 kB/s
AES-CBC                        : 1330523 kB/s
AES-GCM                        : 3346640 k
```

Instead of GB/s you should really be looking at ns per kB, that way you can add the processing time together and then calculate it back to GB/s as you want.

Now we can calculate the speed of SHA-1 + CBC by performing:

$$T_{SHA-1\&CBC} = {1 \over {1 \over T_{SHA-1}} + {1 \over T_{AES-CBC}}}$$

where $T$ is the transfer speed in bytes per second.

This will result in the following value: 697876kB/s for SHA-1 + AES-CBC. That means that AES-GCM is about 4.8 times faster than SHA-1 + AES-CBC for a normal, unthreaded implementation. This is  assuming that HMAC has the same speed of SHA-1 (which is approximately true in all probability, even though it has to process a little more data).

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer. 
The only thing I don't get is why you chose cbc mode? 
I chose ctr + hmac sha1 because thats the default for srtp protocol

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought that you'd use TLS, because you were referencing OpenSSL. I don't have much time right now, can you get along with the given answer to calculate the aggregate result? I presume that most protocols will not multi-thread for one specific connection, so it should in that case be a valid way of calculating the speed.